# unqualified-id error before ')' token

Tags: c++, class, graph

I am new to stack overflow and I would appreciate feedback. I am creating a template graph class and have split it into two files graph.h and graph.hpp, but everytime I compile I get this error:

```
    In file included from graph.h:97:0,
                     from main.cpp:2:
    graph.hpp:4:26: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
     typename graph<T>::graph(){
                          ^
makefile:2: recipe for target 'executable.x' failed
```

Here is my graph.hpp file so far:

```
#include "graph.h"

//template <typename T>
typename graph<T>::graph(){
   numVertices = 0;
   graphWeight = 0;
}
```

And my graph.h file looks something like:

```
template <typename T>
class graph{

   public:
      graph();
.
.
.
   private:



};
```

Also, my main.cpp is just simply:

```
#include "graph.h"

int main(){
   graph<int> g;

}
```

What could possibly be wrong? I know it's probably something simple that has to do with the template.

Thanks

Comment: Uncomment `template <typename T>`, delete `typename` that follows.

Answer (score 0):

In your graph.hpp snippet, change your code to this

```
#include "graph.h"

template <typename T>
graph<T>::graph(){    //Constructor has no return type.
   numVertices = 0;
   graphWeight = 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, you have cannot really have separate header and implementation file for templates, so put the implementation in your header file. For more info and workarounds, see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Thanks! Will look into it!